# Handle unobserved categories when group by SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, missing-data

I have a question about handling unobserved categories when group by it.
For example,

```
Month   Number
Jan.    1
Jan.    4
Mar.    5
Apr.    3
July.   1
Sept.   4
Nov.    7
Nov.    8
Dec.    9
Dec.    1
Dec.    2
```

If I use this query

```
select t.Month, sum(t.Number) as sum from table t group by t.Month;
```

It will just return a table like this

```
Month   sum
Jan.    5
Mar.    5
Apr.    3
July.   1
Sept.   4
Nov.    15
Dec.    12
```

But what I want to get is actually this

```
Month   sum
Jan.    5
Feb.    0
Mar.    5
Apr.    3
May.    0
June.   0
July.   1
Aug.    0
Sept.   4
Oct.    0
Nov.    15
Dec.    12
```

It will also include those unobserved months and return values as 0.

How could I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` a calendar, group by the calendar's month.

```
select cd.months, coalesce(sum(t.Number),0) as 'sum' 
from (
SELECT 'Jan.' as 'months' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Feb.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mar.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Apr.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'May.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'June.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'July.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aug.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sept.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Oct.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nov.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dec.' 
) cd LEFT JOIN T on cd.months = t.Month
group by cd.months;
```

sqlfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1aca12dbcc087ce85145e3a8919a6182

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left outer join`, where the left side is a table of all the months and the right side is a table of values associated with each month. Here's an example:

Create a table of months (1 represents January - you can also stick to month names if that's easier):

```
create table month (month int);
insert into month values
    (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12);
```

The table of summable values associated with each month:

```
create table month_val (month int, val int);
insert into month_val values
    (1, 10), (1, 11), (2, 20), (2, 21), (3, 30);
```

Left join the tables:

```
select month.month, coalesce(sum(month_val.val), 0)
from month
left join month_val on (month.month = month_val.month)
group by month.month
```

Result:

```
month   coalesce(sum(month_val.val), 0)
1   21
2   41
3   30
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
```

You can of course use month names instead of month numbers or convert a month number into a name using a function specific to your database.